# AudioStreams are not closing

Tags: java, javasound

I am trying to get two **.wav** files, convert them to the same audio format and then concatenate. I need only concatenated files and delete the others. The problem is that I can not delete them because AudioInputStreams are not closed. After debugging I discovered that streams are not closed after execution of this method:

```
private static void convertFilesToSameAudioFormat(String fileName1, String fileName2) {
        try (AudioInputStream clip = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(fileName2));
             AudioInputStream clip1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(fileName1));
             AudioInputStream clip2 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(clip1.getFormat(), clip);) {
            AudioSystem.write(clip2,
                    AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE,
                    new File("temp.wav"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

So after the execution of this method clip, clip1, clip2 can not be deleted, because they are used by the program.

Comment: The code does close the streams, at least when I run this snippet. You are not doing in the code what you describing in your problem. Can you include how you are deleting the files and what kind of errors you get.

Comment: I tried to call `System.gc()` at the end of this method and it worked. This solution is described in the post below.

Comment: Calling `System.gc()` after this method is not relevant for anything in this context.
If you have problems to delete an open file from your code, you should include that code in your question. Could you update your code with that?